# How can I save my result to workspace in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Here is my dummy code to create M and V.

```
function [M,V] = likelihood(xTrain, yTrain)
    M = zeros(5, 5)
    V = zeros(5, 5)
    rows = size(xTrain, 1)
    classCount = zeros(5, 1)

    for i = 1 : 5
        for j = 1 : rows
            class = yTrain(j)
            M(class, i) = M(class, i) + xTrain(j, i)
        end
    end

    for i = 1:5
         classCount(i) = sum(yTrain == i)
    end

    for k = 1 : 5
        M(:, k) = M(:, k) ./ classCount
    end

    for i = 1:5
        for j = 1:rows
            class = yTrain(j)
            V(class, i) = V(class, i)+ abs(xTrain(j, i) - M(class, i))
        end
    end

    for k = 1 : 5
        V(:, k) = V(:, k) ./ classCount
    end
end
```

The problem I meet here is since I want to use M and V later, I want to save it in the workspace and I suppose it would create M and V in workspace but it didn't. Instead, matlab continuously update the variable ans which is not what I expected.

Comment: make sure to call your function this way `[M,V] = likelihood(xTrain, yTrain)` and not `likelihood(xTrain, yTrain)`

Comment: It is *exactly* as expected that MATLAB updates the `ans` each time, since you do not call you function properly. See @HamtaroWarrior 's comment

Answer (score -3, accepted):

M and V wont change unless you close the MATLAB or use them again as a new variables.
when and where do you exactly want these two?

Comment: This looks like it should have been a comment and not an answer.